# How do I calculate the sum of column when there is a condition in SQLite Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I want to use SQLite3 Swift to do a calculation that accumulates values ​​when the flag is 0 and subtracts them from the accumulated value when it is 1.

I also want to get the average of the cumulative values ​​only if Flag is 0, and I want to get the previous average value if it is 1.

I attached the picture.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or better, window functions make getting the `RsSum` results easy. It took me a while to figure out how the `RsAvg` numbers are calculated, but I was able to get those values too:

```sql
CREATE TABLE input(no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, flag INTEGER, amt NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO input(no, flag, amt)
VALUES (1, 0, 10), (2, 0, 20), (3, 0, 30), (4, 1, 10), (5, 0, 10), (6, 0, 20)
     , (7, 1, 30);

WITH
  sumcte AS (
   SELECT no, flag
        , sum(CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN amt ELSE -amt END) OVER (ORDER BY no) AS RsSum
   FROM input)
, avgcte AS (
   SELECT no, flag, RsSum
        , cast(RsSum AS REAL) / count(no) FILTER (WHERE flag = 0)
                                          OVER (ORDER BY no) As RsAvg
   FROM sumcte)
SELECT RsSum
     , (CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN RsAvg
             ELSE lag(RsAvg, 1) OVER (ORDER BY no) END) As RsAvg
FROM avgcte ORDER BY no;
```

produces

```
RsSum       RsAvg     
----------  ----------
10          10.0
30          15.0
60          20.0
50          20.0
60          15.0
80          16.0
50          16.0
```

(Interpreting `RsAvg` as that row's `RsSum` divided by the number of rows seen so far where `flag` is 0 is the only way I could make the numbers work.)

This will break when two rows in a row have a `flag` of 1, though. I'll update again if I figure a workaround for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the entities based on the condition (flag == 0) using some `NSPredicate` kind of function.

Then you can add the values of the sequence (`sum1`) using the `reduce(_:_:)` function.

Now that you have the `sum1`, you can similarly filter the (flag == 1) entities.

Use reduce function again on the sequence to get their `sum2`. Subtract sum2 from `sum`.